# Making Flutter plugins for Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

good day.
I am somewhat new to Flutter, but I am in need of having my own plugin since I need to implement C++ code in my app and use its functions.
Unfortunately, I haven't found an article for making my own **Windows desktop**, can I know the following?

1. Do I need to know to code in C++?
2. Where to start? How can I use a C++ library in my app?
3. I only know Flutter + Dart, is there any other language I need to learn?

Comment: To build a Flutter plugin for Windows Desktop, you need to write C++ code. Reference https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-github-graphql-client/index.html#5